# NSNetserviceBrowser delegate method is not firing

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

I am doing one application. In that I am publishing the service using `NsNetservice` and browse using `NSNetserviceBrowser`. But sometimes service publish the services successfully, but browser not able to find that service using `didFindservice` delegate method. Only `netServiceBrowserWillSearch` is firing and `didNotsearch` delegate method is also not firing. And if I restart the devices then it's working correctly.

Please help me how to resolve this problem.Code for browser and service please check below

**Browser:**

```
  self.browser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
self.browser.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
[self.browser setDelegate:self];
[self.browser searchForServicesOfType:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@._tcp.",serviceName,Name] inDomain:@""];
```

**Service:**

```
  self.netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"" type:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@._tcp.",serviceName,Name] name:Name port:randomPortNumber];
self.netService.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
[self.netService setDelegate:self];
 [self.netService scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.netService publishWithOptions:NSNetServiceListenForConnections];
```

Comment: code? past your code to we can identify you problem !

Comment: Please check the code

Comment: have you added <NSNetserviceBrowserDelegate> in your interface?

Comment: Yes added that delegate.